# Create Pivot Table Based on Dynamic Range

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, pivot-table

I am trying to create a macro that will take data that starts at A18, find the last row and last column then generate a pivot table. I searched around to take bits and pieces from code I found online to try to make something work.

I keep getting a 1004 error, and I suspect it is because my code isn't actually selecting the data range properly.

this is the code that the error happens on:

```
Set pvtable = pvcache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=pvsheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="Payroll")
```

this is all of the code:

```
    Dim pvtable As PivotTable
  Dim pvcache As PivotCache
  Dim ptrange As Range
  Dim pvsheet As Worksheet
  Dim pdsheet As Worksheet
  Dim plr As Long
  Dim plc As Long
  Dim startCell As Range

  On Error Resume Next
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Worksheets("Pivot table").Delete 'to delete the existing pivot table in the worksheet
  Worksheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet ' to add a new worksheet

  ActiveSheet.Name = "Pivot Table" ' to rename the worksheet
  
  On Error GoTo 0

  Set pvsheet = Worksheets("Pivot table")
  Set pdsheet = Worksheets("sheet1")
  Set startCell = Range("A18")
  
  

  'two variable to find Last used row and column in sheet 1, raw data'
  
  
  plr = pdsheet.Cells(pdsheet.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
  plc = pdsheet.Cells(startCell.Row, pdsheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 

  'set range from selected data


Set ptrange = pdsheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(plr, plc)


  'pivot cahe needed for data load
  
  Set pvcache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, SourceData:=ptrange)

  'create empty pivot table
  Set pvtable = pvcache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=pvsheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="Payroll")

  'Insert worker to Row Filed
  With pvsheet.PivotTables("Payroll").PivotFields("Worker")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
  End With

  'Insert Street to Row Filed & position 2
  With pvsheet.PivotTables("Payroll").PivotFields("Actual Hours")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
  End With

  'to show the pivot table in Tabular form
  pvsheet.PivotTables("Payroll").RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow

  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I am suspecting the issue is within this area here where the data range is selected to make the pivot table:

```
 Set pvsheet = Worksheets("Pivot table")
      Set pdsheet = Worksheets("sheet1")
      Set startCell = Range("A18")
      
      
    
      'two variable to find Last used row and column in sheet 1, raw data'
      
      
      plr = pdsheet.Cells(pdsheet.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
      plc = pdsheet.Cells(startCell.Row, pdsheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
     
    
      'set range from selected data
    
    
    Set ptrange = pdsheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(plr, plc)
```

any help appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining your range as follows...

```
Set ptrange = pdsheet.Range(startCell, pdsheet.Cells(plr, plc))
```

Or, alternatively...

```
Set pdsheet = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set startCell = pdsheet.Range("A18")

With pdsheet
  plr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
  plc = .Cells(startCell.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  Set ptrange = .Range(startCell, .Cells(plr, plc))
End With
```

Comment: thank you so much! the second option worked! can you explain it a bit so I understand? really appreciate it!

Comment: The second one uses the `With/End With` statement to refer to the worksheet, which in this case is `pdsheet`.  So any reference within this statement that starts with a dot (.) will refer to `pdsheet`.  It's simply a more efficient way of referring to the sheet when there are multiple references.